# Fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $post_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\couponer\functions.php on line 2533

Tags: php, wordpress

I am Getting error

> Fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $post_id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\couponer\functions.php on line 2533

```
function coupon_smeta_images( $meta_key, $post_id, $default, $post_id){
    if(class_exists('SM_Frontend')){
        global $sm;
        return $result = $sm->sm_get_meta($meta_key, $post_id);
    }
    else{       
        return $default;
    }
}

/* check if smeta plugin is installed */
```

Comment: You have `$post_id` in your function construction twice.

Comment: As mentioned, you are using `$post_id` as two separate parameters to this function.  Although I'm also a bit concerned about the fact it's on line 2533, probably toooo much code in one file?

Comment: This is a Wordpress theme function File. I Dont know How to solve this error can you Suggect something

Comment: function coupon_smeta_images( $meta_key, **$post_id**, $default, **$post_id**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a duplicate `$post_id` parameters in your functions. Try remove one like this:

```
function coupon_smeta_images( $meta_key, $post_id, $default){
    if(class_exists('SM_Frontend')){
        global $sm;
        return $result = $sm->sm_get_meta($meta_key, $post_id);
    }
    else{       
        return $default;
    }
}
```