# On trying to login to wordpress backend on website/wp-admin the following error comes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

> Fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $options in
>   /home/content/p3pnexwpnas04_data03/16/42080916/html/wp-content/themes/himmelen/inc/oneclick-demo-import/importer/radium-importer.php
>   on line 313

I don't know what this means, can someone help me to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack.  It looks like the theme has some not great code. You can see that the message relates to the theme by the url in the message.

To get rid of it, Logon to your control panel and rename the theme folder.  This will cause it to deactivate and wp should revert to default theme (make sure there is a default theme there too).

You can then either take it up with the theme support, or use another theme.

If you are the theme author, note that the parameter may have been defined twice.  A quick google found this [Fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $post_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\couponer\functions.php on line 2533](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661403/fatal-error-redefinition-of-parameter-post-id-in-c-xampp-htdocs-wp-content-th)